# Xamarin Android - List View not responding to click

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, click

**Hi all!**

Please see here for a visual explanation (using an android emulator):
https://gyazo.com/225f0913f936a7f0e62769799083ce18

Recently I've been developing an application for a college assignment, however, i have run into a problem with a ListView ClickItem that when the user clicks one of the items in the list the drawer layout closes and the click on the ListView doesn't register at all.

**MainActivity.cs**

```
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout (Resource.Id.drawer_layout);    
ListView mContentDrawer = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.content_drawer);

//Drawer layout lock
mDrawerLayout.SetDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LockModeLockedClosed);
//Click listener for drawer layout
mContentDrawer.ItemClick += MContentDrawer_ItemClick;

private void MContentDrawer_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            //Temporary Toast (will change once click is working):
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Clicked: " + mContentDataset[e.Position], ToastLength.Short).Show();

            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

*Side note*: I plan to change the toast output to an activity change once the click listener works, I know how to do this but I haven't implemented it because I need to get the click listener working first.

**Main.axml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!--Content Navigation Drawer-->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/content_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:divider="#ffdfe0"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#4b2b2c" />
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#EFEFEF"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/grid">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/statsBtn"
            android:src="@drawable/statistics"
            android:background="@drawable/statistics"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:padding="10dp" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/contentBtn"
            android:src="@drawable/content"
            android:background="@drawable/content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:padding="10dp" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/emergencyBtn"
            android:src="@drawable/emergency"
            android:background="@drawable/emergency"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:padding="10dp" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/contactBtn"
            android:src="@drawable/contact"
            android:background="@drawable/contact"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:padding="10dp" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/websiteBtn"
            android:background="@drawable/website"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/website"
            android:padding="10dp" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/settingsBtn"
            android:src="@drawable/settings"
            android:background="@drawable/settings"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:padding="10dp" />
    </GridLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Does anyone know how i can fix this so that when the user clicks on one of the items in the list view it triggers and outputs toast like shown above?

Kind Regards

Comment: The drawer in a `DrawerLayout` must be listed last inside the `<DrawerLayout>` tags. Move the `<ListView>` to after the `<GridLayout>`.

Comment: *facepalms*, thanks so much